# Custom STS and Azure AD Federation Issue Due to User Provisioning

Tags: office365, azure-active-directory, saml, saml-2.0, lync-2013

**Requirement:** Want to certify our custom STS implementation to federate with Azure Active Directory. Followed steps given in the doc ["STS Integration Paper using WS-* Protocols - Federation with Azure Active Directory"](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41185).

To test the custom STS implementation, I have a desktop Lync 2013 active client (uses Microsoft Online Services Sign-In Assistant), which tries to authenticate the user against custom STS with a federated domain in Azure AD.

**Issue:** Custom STS sends RSTR with SAML1.1 token in response to Lync's RST. But then the request (RST) from Lync client to https://login.microsoftonline.com/RST2.srf end with fault response as ***"Provision is needed before federated account can be logged in".***

I did follow the suggestions from these forum links [1](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bcb8d97b-0043-46c8-86ee-f7083b21e966/acs20012-the-request-is-not-a-valid-wsfederation-protocol-message?forum=WindowsAzureAD) & [2](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/2b72a210-6a6e-4add-a420-f3fd81c68532/how-to-provision-federated-single-signon-enabled-user-accounts-in-windows-azure-ad-without-using?forum=WindowsAzureAD#2b72a210-6a6e-4add-a420-f3fd81c68532), where custom STS sends SAML token with ImmutableID and objectGUID value as "4BNAbdFMKEe5xCw5iY2tYQ==" for the authenticated user.

**Note:** In Azure AD, the test user is mentioned as Sourced From "Microsoft Azure Active Directory" and no directory synchronization between Azure AD and on-prem directory exist.

Am I missing any vital step custom STS implementation or in the user creation/ configuration? Please suggest your inputs.

Answer (score 1):

**Found the solution:** Since no directory sync exist, I created a new user at Microsoft Azure Active Directory and the custom STS sends SAML token with ImmutableID and objectGUID with value in Base64 solved the issue. 
So basically follow this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/2b72a210-6a6e-4add-a420-f3fd81c68532/how-to-provision-federated-single-signon-enabled-user-accounts-in-windows-azure-ad-without-using?forum=WindowsAzureAD#2b72a210-6a6e-4add-a420-f3fd81c68532), if anyone encounter same issue.